# Msg 9828 Level 16 translate using hexa code

Tags: sql, sql-server

Translate function in SQL Server works as such:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('titi', 'it', 'ol')
```

returns lolo.

But is it possible to use an hexa code, for example because you want to replace it by blanks ?

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('titi', '\x80', ' ')
```

I get this error:

> Msg 9828 Level 16 State 1
> Second and third arguments from integrated function TRANSLATE must contain the same number of characters

Comment: It should be `\x80\x80` (two bytes = two spaces).

Comment: That won't work, @l'L'l . `\x80\x80` will give a syntax error, and `'\x80\x80'` would be interpreted as the literal string value.

Comment: @ThomA, ah, i see. It seemed liked there where two characters third field, but apparently not. Why didn't a syntax error occur when he tried it the first time?

Comment: `SELECT TRANSLATE('titi', 'it', 'ol')` is valid syntax, @l'L'l. It will repalce all `i` characters with `o` and all `t` characters with `l`.

Comment: Seems like you're looking for the `CHAR()` function, e.g.: `SELECT TRANSLATE(REPLICATE(CHAR(128), 10), CHAR(0x80), 'x');`

Comment: @ThornA, oh so not possible to use Hexadecimal, gotcha. thanks!

Comment: You can use binary value, yes, @l'L'l , but you'll need to do what AlwaysLearning just demonstrated (I was literally typing a similar comment at the time but with `CONVERT`)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, if you want to replace multiple values (the whole point of using TRANSLATE), would you use CONCAT(CHAR(0x80), CHAR(0x99), ...) for example ?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, SELECT TRANSLATE( CONCAT(REPLICATE(CHAR(0x80), 10), REPLICATE(CHAR(0x99), 10)),  CONCAT(CHAR(0x80), CHAR(0x99)), 'xy') works. If you post it as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CHAR() function, in combination with CONCAT() as the replace lists can be built dynamically.

```
SELECT TRANSLATE( CONCAT(REPLICATE(CHAR(0x80), 10), REPLICATE(CHAR(0x99), 10)), CONCAT(CHAR(0x80), CHAR(0x99)), 'xy')
```

returns

```
xxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyy
```